# Unittests with custom user model

Tags: python, django

I have the following error while trying to run unittests:

command:

```
python manage.py test wall
```

output:

```
wall.wall: 'author' has a relation with model accounts.Account, which has either not been installed or is abstract.

(list of other models, which have their links to accounts.Account)
```

Code snippets:

So, we have inherited from AbstractBaseUser in the following way:

**accounts/models.py:**

```
from wall.models import Wall
...

class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(...)
    name = models.CharField(...)
    wall = GenericRelation(Wall, content_type_field='object_type', object_id_field='object_id')
    ...

class UserAccount(Account):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        verbose_name = 'User'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.is_organization = False
        self.is_charity = False

        super(UserAccount, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**wall/models.py**

```
class Wall(TimeStampedModel):
    objects = WallManager()

    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    content = models.TextField()
```

settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Account' - in settings file.

**wall/tests.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase
from accounts.models import UserAccount
from wall.models import Wall

class WallTests(TestCase):

    def test_simple_wall_post(self):    
        jacob = UserAccount.objects.create_user(
            username='jacob', email='jacob@...', password='top_secret')
        kyle = self.user = UserAccount.objects.create_user(
            username='kyle', email='kyle@...', password='top_secret_2')

        Wall.objects.create_post(author=jacob, title="I'm posting on your wall",
                                 content="this is a random message",
                                 object=kyle)
        wall_item = Wall.objects.get(author=jacob, object=kyle)
        self.assertEqual(wall_item.author, jacob)
```

When moving

```
from accounts.models import UserAccount
```

inside **test_simple_wall_post()** function, the problem disappears. This is obviously not convenient though. So what causes the abstract bug? I have imported non abstract model, so it is very strange to me.

Comment: It looks like a import cycle - maybe the ``wall.models`` module imports something else?